# How to uninstall a flask larger app package?

Tags: python, flask

According to the Flask Larger App tutorial:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/

You need to install the project using:

```
pip install -e .
```

But what if I want to uninstall it?

I tried

```
pip uninstall .
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to uninstall (see "pip help uninstall")
```

Also does a conflict can occur if I clone my project and forgot to change the package name to make it unique.

Comment: You will need to provide the *actual* package name that was referenced originally when you installed `.`, e.g. If you saw `Successfully installed yourapplication`, you will need to issue `pip uninstall yourapplication`.

Comment: and in consquence, that package name has to be unique, right ?

Comment: It should be, otherwise installation of a different package with the same name as an existing, installed package, will force an uninstallation of that.  Read the console output that `pip` generates, it should be self-explanatory as it will tell you `Found existing installation:` of whatever existing.